# Derivative of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of real symmetric, positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

> Given a system of linear differential equations specifying the time evolution of a covariance matrix, how to rewrite it in terms of differential equations for that matrix's SVD?

---

You are given a square matrix, $A$, whose elements are functions of time. At all times, from $t=0$ onward, $A$ is a real, symmetric, and positive definite matrix. You have a system of equations for $\dot A$ and an SVD at time zero, which establishes initial values for its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Write a system of differential equations for its eigenvalues and eigenvectors in terms of the elements of $A$. If it is possible to do so, write equations that work even if the eigenvalues are not distinct.

Let $v$ be the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$. I got.

$$\mathbf{v}^\intercal (dA) v = d\lambda$$

How to solve for the eigenvectors?

Note: My aim is to avoid having to do an eigenvalue/vector calculation at each time step.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have been searching for the past week

Comment: Take a look at [this book](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~john/papers/BOOK/B04.PDF).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo They are linear

Comment: Please provide that system of ODEs.